# Regex find all reference of a function and replace/add a param to all instances

Tags: python, regex, visual-studio-code, regex-group, regexp-replace

After change or add a parameter in a function definition, I want to update all references of that function across all files to have the updated parameter.

I use multiple-file search/replace in VSCode and do it with regular expression.

A few requirements

- this param could be in other functions
- function reference could be in multiple lines
- don't update the function references that do not use this parameter

for example, I want to rename param_2 of function_A to new_param_2

```
  function_A(
    param_1 = ....  # this function_A shall not be matched because it doesn't use param_2
)

  function_A(
    param_1 = .... 
    param_2 = aaa  # only this param_2 shall be renamed to new_param_2
)

  function_B(
    param_1 = .... 
    param_2 = aaa  # this param_2 shall not be matched because it's not in function_A
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this regex below to match and capture groups

```
(function_A(?:[^)]|\n)+?\W)(param_2)(\W?=)
```

In which,

- `(?:[^)]|\n)+?` performance a lazy matches multiple lines after function_A and before ')', it is a non-capture group.
- `\W)(param_2)(\W?=)` these \W is to accommodate linting differences

then, I use regex below to replace and substitute

```
$1new_param_2$3
```

By doing that, I am able to replace all instances of the functions at once across all files.

[UPDATE]
**CAVEAT**: this could fail if there is a ')' before param_2, e.g., function_A(param_1=sin(1.0), param_2=2,...). If that doesn't occur in the code base, then this could work. [Credit to @RootTwo]

[image]

Comment: This may be good enough, but fails if there is a ')' before `param_2`, e.g., `function_A(param_1=sin(1.0), param_2=2,...)`.  If the user knows that doesn't occur in the code base, then this could work.

Comment: Thank you @RootTwo, that's a great point. I will add it to the Exception.